# Database won't stay updated after switching script

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update this database, and I've verified within this script that the update is completed, and that the $nw and $p variables are correct.

```
<?php
session_start();
$num = (int) $_SESSION["cart"];
$cart = $num + 1;
$_SESSION["cart"] = (string) $cart;
$nme = $_POST['nameofitem'];
$pst = $_SESSION["user"];
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'spj916', "cs4501", 'spj916');
$query = "select * from Items where Items.Id = '$nme'";
$result = $db->query($query) or die ($db->error);
$item = $result->fetch_array();
$nw = $item[5] - 1;
$p = (int) $pst;
echo $p;
$query3 = "update Items set Quantity = '$nw' where Id = '$p'";
$db->query($query3) or die ("Invalid insert " . $db->error);
$query2 = "insert into Bought (Name, Cost, BuyerID) values ('$item[1]', '$item[4]', '$pst')";
$db->query($query2) or die ("Invalid insert " . $db->error);
header("Location: store.php");
?>
```

However, when it redirects to this script, it echoes the information as if it weren't updated. What is the problem?

```
<?php
session_start();
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'spj916', "cs4501", 'spj916');
$user = $_SESSION["user"];
$pw = $_SESSION["pw"];
# determines number of items in cart to display
if (!isset($_SESSION["category"]))
   $_SESSION["category"] = "Book";
if (isset($_POST["Ccategory"])) {
   $cat = $_POST["Ccategory"];
   $_SESSION["category"] = $cat;
}
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart"]))
   $_SESSION["cart"] = "0";
$cart = $_SESSION["cart"];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php # setting up table with items to buy ?>
<table border = "1" border-spacing = "5px" >
<caption><h2> UVA Bookstore 2.0</h2>
<p align=right> Items in cart: <?php echo $cart?> </p> <br />
     <b><i>Welcome to the new and improved bookstore with a better selection than ever</i></b>
     <br/><br/>
</caption>
<tr align = "center">
  <th>Item</th>
  <th>Description</th>
  <th>Price</th>
  <th>Number left</th>
  <th>Buy</th>
</tr>
<?php
  $category = $_SESSION["category"];
  $query = "select * from Items where Items.Category = '$category'";
  $result = $db->query($query) or die ($db->error);
  $rows = $result->num_rows;
     for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++)
     {
    $row = $result->fetch_array();
?>
    <form action="addtocart.php"
              method="POST">
         <tr align = "center">
         <td>
<?php 
         echo $row[1];
?>
         </td>
         <td> <?php echo $row[3];?> </td>
     <td> <?php echo $row[4];?> </td>
     <td> <?php echo $row[5];?> </td>
     <?php # sets up add to cart button that adds item to cart ?>
         <td> <input type = "hidden" name ='nameofitem' 
                           value= "<?php echo $row[0]?>"> 

              <input type='submit' value='Add to Cart'> </input> </td>
         </tr>
     </form>
<?php
     }
# form to check out and go to summary page ?>
<form action = "store.php"
      method = "POST">
<tr align = "center"> <td>
<select name = "Ccategory">
  <option value = "Book">Books</option>
  <option value = "Music">Music</option>
  <option value = "Car">Cars</option>
</select>
<input type = "hidden" name = "cat"> </td>
<td> <input type = "submit" value = "Switch Category"> </td>
</form>
<form action="summary.php" 
      method="POST">
     <td> <input type = "submit" value = "Check out"> </td> </tr>
</table><br/>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: This code is subject to SQL Injection vulnerabilities. The OWASP project provides some useful insight ...[https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: I don't really understand this. Can you tell me what I did wrong? I'm under serious time constraint.

Comment: “I've verified within this script that the update is completed, and that the $nw and $p variables are correct”: you echo `$p` variable before executing update query. How have you verified that update is ok? look at phpmyadmin to see if the field value is really updated.

Comment: @BobJones As for the sql injection, you should not be putting variables right into your sql, like this `"update Items set Quantity = '$nw' where Id = '$p'"` and `"select * from Items where Items.Category = '$category'"`. A savvy sql tinkerer could inject some malicious sql in there and you will find your database compromised, if not wiped completely. Look up `bind_param`

Comment: Ok then SQL injection isn't the problem because this is just a homework assignment and I'm just using a local database. But I looked at phpmyadmin, and it turns out it's not updating. What could be the problem?

Comment: Echo your sql statements like `die($query3);` see if it's what you expect.

Comment: Also, if you are allowed to use functions, you would benefit a lot by doing so.

Comment: Lastly, sql injection could be an issue if someone types a character that is reserved for sql like `'` or `;` or `%`, etc. Characters like that can mess with and unparameterized query.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing

```
$query3 = "update Items set Quantity = '$nw' where Id = '$p'";
```

to

```
$query3 = "update Items set Quantity = '$nw' where Id = $p";
```

The best way to determine if an `UPDATE` should work is to replace it with a `SELECT` containing the same `WHERE` clause.  This way you can see what rows would be changed if you were to run the original query.

Otherwise, it seems to be the case that your changes in the current transaction are never committed.  Is this the only script that has an issue with updates to the database?  Please see the PHP manual for more information:

```
//mysqli::commit -- mysqli_commit — Commits the current transaction
bool mysqli::commit ([ int $flags [, string $name ]] )
```

A commit should be issued when you are done doing all updates that have dependencies (or for those that are atomic), however, you don't always have to commit depending on the configuration of your server.  Also, it looks like your script has SQL injection vulnerabilities as other have mentioned.  It would probably be best to use prepared statements or sanitize your inputs.

Comment: I can insert elements to the database, but this is the only script where I try to update a row.

Comment: How do you know that the row is being updated?  You may not get an error but it could be the case that your ```WHERE``` clause is not matching anything.  Honestly, I think it's because you are treating ```$p``` as a string in your query instead of an integer.  Is the ```Id``` supposed to be a string?  That's probably your issue; just remove the single quotes.

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue?  I would like some feedback.

Comment: It did not fix the problem

Comment: Could you please update the question with the schema of the database/table(s) in question?  It looks like this question is for a school assignment, so there must be something very simple that you're doing wrong.